# inline style changes by javascript don't work on mobile browsers (chrome/dolphin/android): why?

Tags: javascript, android, css, mobile

[jfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lbwyya1/3/)

**expected behavior (as performed on pc/windows browser)**: h1 header "gif" disappears and video plays

**mobile behavior**: gif does not disappear- but video *does* play (so js is firing)

why doesn't the display toggle work on mobile (android) chrome the way it does in windows chrome?

relivant code:

```
this.play();
this.removeAttribute("controls"); //works
//h1.style.display="none"; //does not work
this.previousSibling.style.display="none"; //does not work
```

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` is not a valid event in touch devices. Try `ontouchstart` for mobile version. Also touch event object doesn't contain `offsetY`. Instead, you can use `pageY` on both mobile and desktop browsers.

Here is the working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilkumar80/5Lbwyya1/11/).

Comment: I'm sorry but this (your link) is not working (at least not as expected: header "gif" does not disappear on playback for android/chrome)... 

and also your statement is not entirely true. touch *does* work with android mobile as "mouse click" is emulated by touch -though this approach is not universal for mobile....

as I stated in the question, the *javascript* function fires just fine, it's the changing of style.display = "block" which does not work on mobile devices.

Comment: Video is playing because of the `onplay` event. When you tap on the video `onplay` is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the show/hide functions and attached them to the onplay/onpause events of the video element.

I don't know why it didn't work the other way, but this solution works as expected. see code below:

```
vidx.onplay = function() {
    h1.style.display="none";
    vidx.removeAttribute("controls");
}

vidx.onpause = function() {
    h1.style.display="block";
    vidx.setAttribute("controls","true");
}
```